# Functions within a loop called multiple times. How could I go about this in a different way?

Tags: javascript, loops, gsap

My moveMask function in the code below is called x amount of times for each HTML element with the class `.layout-box`.

I'm struggling to think of a way of re-writing my code so that it only runs the functions once, each time an event listener is invoked.

I understand this might not be a simple fix, but if I could get some some idea of the direction I need to be heading in, then I'd really appreciate it.

```
// Store SVG container element as variable
var layoutBox = document.querySelectorAll(".layout-box"),
    xPos = 0,
    yPos = 0,
    elOver = true,
    clicked = false,
    rect,
    coords,
    split = document.querySelectorAll('.words h2, .words h3, .words p, .words li');

// GSAP tweens/functions that require access to coordinates
function moveMask(valueX, valueY) {
    [].slice.call(layoutBox).forEach(function(el, i) {
        console.log("test");
        var img = el.querySelectorAll('.img');

        // Mask move animation 
        var tlMove = new TimelineMax({
            paused: true
        });
        tlMove.set(img, {
            webkitClipPath: '40px at ' + valueX + 'px ' + valueY + 'px'
        });
        el.animationMaskMove = tlMove;

        // Mask click animation
        var tlClick = tlLeave = new TimelineMax({
            paused: true
        });
        tlClick.to(img, 0.8, {
            webkitClipPath: '500px at ' + valueX + 'px ' + valueY + 'px',
        });
        tlClick.to(img, 0.4, {
            '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale(0%)',
             filter: 'grayscale(0%)'
        }, '-=0.8');
        el.animationMaskClick = tlClick;
        tlClick.progress(1).progress(0); // Forces an initial render of this tween so that it's cached for its 2nd usage

        // Mask leave animation
        var tlLeave = new TimelineMax({
            paused: true
        });
        tlLeave.to(img, 0.2, {
            webkitClipPath: '0 at ' + valueX + 'px ' + valueY + 'px',
            '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale(100%)',
             filter: 'grayscale(100%)'
        });
        el.animationMaskLeave = tlLeave;
        tlLeave.progress(1).progress(0);

        // Mask slow leave animation
        var tlLeaveSlow = new TimelineMax({
            paused: true
        });
        tlLeaveSlow.to(img, 0.6, {
            ease: Bounce.easeOut,
            webkitClipPath: '0 at ' + valueX + 'px ' + valueY + 'px',
            '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale(100%)',
             filter: 'grayscale(100%)'
        });
        el.animationMaskSlowLeave = tlLeaveSlow;
        tlLeaveSlow.progress(1).progress(0);

    });
}

// Force initial run with temporary coordinates (so tweens can be cached)
moveMask(-100, -100);

// GSAP tweens/functions that don't access to coordinates
[].slice.call(layoutBox).forEach(function(el, i) {
    console.log("test2");
    var svgContainer = el.querySelectorAll('.svg-container');
    var svgContainerLeft = el.querySelectorAll('.left');
    var svgContainerBottom = el.querySelectorAll('.bottom');
    var img = el.querySelectorAll('.img');
    var mask = el.querySelectorAll('.mask');
    var text = el.querySelectorAll('.text');
    var elSplit = el.querySelectorAll('.words');

    // Container 3d push effect 
    var tlContainer3d = new TimelineMax({
        paused: true
    });
    tlContainer3d.to(svgContainer, 0.3, {
        x: "-=6px",
        y: "+=6px"
    });
    el.animationContainer3d = tlContainer3d;
    tlContainer3d.progress(1).progress(0);

    // Container 3d push effect left
    var tlContainer3dLeft = new TimelineMax({
        paused: true
    });
    tlContainer3dLeft.to(svgContainerLeft, 0.3, {
        width: "4px"
    });
    el.animationContainer3dLeft = tlContainer3dLeft;
    tlContainer3dLeft.progress(1).progress(0);

    // Container 3d push effect bottom
    var tlContainer3dBottom = new TimelineMax({
        paused: true
    });
    tlContainer3dBottom.to(svgContainerBottom, 0.3, {
        height: "4px",
        right: "+=6px"
    });
    el.animationContainer3dBottom = tlContainer3dBottom;
    tlContainer3dBottom.progress(1).progress(0);

    // Img move animation
    var tlImgMove = new TimelineMax({
        paused: true
    });
    tlImgMove.to(img, 0.3, {
        scale: 1,
        ease: Sine.easeOut,
        '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale(0%)',
         filter: 'grayscale(0%)'
    }, 0.05);
    el.animationImgMove = tlImgMove;
    tlImgMove.progress(1).progress(0);

    // Mask click text animation
    var tlText = new TimelineMax({
        paused: true
    })
    tlText.to(elSplit, .3, {
        autoAlpha: 0
    });
    el.animationTextClick = tlText;
    tlText.progress(1).progress(0);

});

// Loop through boxes and assign event listeners
for (var x = 0; x < layoutBox.length; x++) {

    layoutBox[x].addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {

        if (elOver) { // Only run if mousedown hasn't been triggered

            // Get coordinates of container
            rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            xPos = e.pageX - rect.left;
            yPos = e.pageY - rect.top - window.scrollY;

            // Add coordinates to array and pass in to moveMask function
            coords = [xPos, yPos];
            moveMask.apply(null, coords);

            this.animationMaskMove.play();

        }

    });

    layoutBox[x].addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {

        this.animationContainer3d.play();
        this.animationContainer3dLeft.play();
        this.animationContainer3dBottom.play();
        this.animationMaskClick.play();
        this.animationTextClick.play();
        clicked = true;
        elOver = false;

    });

    layoutBox[x].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(e) {

        this.animationContainer3d.reverse();
        this.animationContainer3dLeft.reverse();
        this.animationContainer3dBottom.reverse();
        this.animationTextClick.timeScale(1.25).reverse();

        // If clicked then run slow animation
        if (clicked) {
            this.animationMaskSlowLeave.play();
        } else {
            this.animationMaskLeave.play();
        }

        clicked = false;
        elOver = true;

    });

}
```

Edit:

```
// Store SVG container element as variable
var layoutBox = document.querySelectorAll(".layout-box"),
    elOver = true,
    clicked = false,
    xPos = 0,
    yPos = 0,
    rect,
    coords;

// GSAP tweens/functions that require access to coordinates
function moveMask(el, valueX, valueY) {
        console.log("test");
        var img = el.querySelectorAll('.img');

        // Mask move animation 
        var tlMove = new TimelineMax({
            paused: true
        });
        tlMove.set(img, {
            webkitClipPath: '40px at ' + valueX + 'px ' + valueY + 'px'
        });
        el.animationMaskMove = tlMove;

        // Mask click animation
        var tlClick = tlLeave = new TimelineMax({
            paused: true
        });
        tlClick.to(img, 0.8, {
            webkitClipPath: '500px at ' + valueX + 'px ' + valueY + 'px',
        });
        tlClick.to(img, 0.4, {
            '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale(0%)',
             filter: 'grayscale(0%)'
        }, '-=0.8');
        el.animationMaskClick = tlClick;
        tlClick.progress(1).progress(0); // Forces an initial render of this tween so that it's cached for its 2nd usage

        // Mask leave animation
        var tlLeave = new TimelineMax({
            paused: true
        });
        tlLeave.to(img, 0.2, {
            webkitClipPath: '0 at ' + valueX + 'px ' + valueY + 'px',
            '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale(100%)',
             filter: 'grayscale(100%)'
        });
        el.animationMaskLeave = tlLeave;
        tlLeave.progress(1).progress(0);

        // Mask slow leave animation
        var tlLeaveSlow = new TimelineMax({
            paused: true
        });
        tlLeaveSlow.to(img, 0.6, {
            ease: Bounce.easeOut,
            webkitClipPath: '0 at ' + valueX + 'px ' + valueY + 'px',
            '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale(100%)',
             filter: 'grayscale(100%)'
        });
        el.animationMaskSlowLeave = tlLeaveSlow;
        tlLeaveSlow.progress(1).progress(0);

}

// Force initial run with temporary coordinates (so tweens can be cached)
[].forEach.call(layoutBox, function(el, i) { moveMask(el, -100, -100) }); 

// GSAP tweens/functions that don't access to coordinates
[].forEach.call(layoutBox, function(el, i) {
    console.log("test2");
    var svgContainer = el.querySelectorAll('.svg-container');
    var svgContainerLeft = el.querySelectorAll('.left');
    var svgContainerBottom = el.querySelectorAll('.bottom');
    var img = el.querySelectorAll('.img');
    var mask = el.querySelectorAll('.mask');
    var text = el.querySelectorAll('.text');
    var elSplit = el.querySelectorAll('.words');

    // Container 3d push effect 
    var tlContainer3d = new TimelineMax({
        paused: true
    });
    tlContainer3d.to(svgContainer, 0.3, {
        x: "-=6px",
        y: "+=6px"
    });
    el.animationContainer3d = tlContainer3d;
    tlContainer3d.progress(1).progress(0);

    // Container 3d push effect left
    var tlContainer3dLeft = new TimelineMax({
        paused: true
    });
    tlContainer3dLeft.to(svgContainerLeft, 0.3, {
        width: "4px"
    });
    el.animationContainer3dLeft = tlContainer3dLeft;
    tlContainer3dLeft.progress(1).progress(0);

    // Container 3d push effect bottom
    var tlContainer3dBottom = new TimelineMax({
        paused: true
    });
    tlContainer3dBottom.to(svgContainerBottom, 0.3, {
        height: "4px",
        right: "+=6px"
    });
    el.animationContainer3dBottom = tlContainer3dBottom;
    tlContainer3dBottom.progress(1).progress(0);

    // Img move animation
    var tlImgMove = new TimelineMax({
        paused: true
    });
    tlImgMove.to(img, 0.3, {
        scale: 1,
        ease: Sine.easeOut,
        '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale(0%)',
         filter: 'grayscale(0%)'
    }, 0.05);
    el.animationImgMove = tlImgMove;
    tlImgMove.progress(1).progress(0);

    // Mask click text animation
    var tlText = new TimelineMax({
        paused: true
    })
    tlText.to(elSplit, .3, {
        autoAlpha: 0
    });
    el.animationTextClick = tlText;
    tlText.progress(1).progress(0);

});

// Event listener functions
function myMouseMove(e) {

        if (elOver) { // Only run if mousedown hasn't been triggered

            // Get coordinates of container
            rect = this.getBoundingClientRect();
            xPos = e.pageX - rect.left; 
            yPos = e.pageY - rect.top - window.scrollY;

            // Add coordinates to array and pass in to moveMask function
            coords = [xPos, yPos];
            moveMask.call(null, coords);

            this.animationMaskMove.play();

        }

}

function myMouseDown(e) {

        this.animationContainer3d.play();
        this.animationContainer3dLeft.play();
        this.animationContainer3dBottom.play();
        this.animationMaskClick.play();
        this.animationTextClick.play();
        clicked = true;
        elOver = false;
};

function myMouseLeave(e) {

        this.animationContainer3d.reverse();
        this.animationContainer3dLeft.reverse();
        this.animationContainer3dBottom.reverse();
        this.animationTextClick.timeScale(1.25).reverse();

        // If clicked then run slow animation
        if (clicked) {
            this.animationMaskSlowLeave.play();
        } else {
            this.animationMaskLeave.play();
        }

        clicked = false;
        elOver = true;

};

// Loop through boxes and assign event listener
for (var x = 0; x < layoutBox.length; x++) {
    layoutBox[x].addEventListener("mousemove", myMouseMove);
    //layoutBox[x].addEventListener("mousedown", this, myMouseDown);
    //layoutBox[x].addEventListener("mouseleave", this, myMouseLeave);
};
```

Comment: Remove the `[].slice.call(layoutBox).forEach(function(el, i) {` from `moveMask`, and instead have it receive an element as a parameter `function moveMask(el, valueX, valueY) {`. Then for the initial call, run it in a loop. `[].slice.call(layoutBox).forEach(function(el, i) { moveMask(el, -100, -100) })` and in the event handlers, have it pass `this` as the first argument.

Comment: Also, move those variable declarations that are only relevant to the inner scope of a function to the functions themselves. And use `.call()` instead of `.apply()` so you don't need to create a temp array. `moveMask.call(null, this, xPos, yPos);`

Comment: Also, you're creating many redundant event handler functions in a loop. Instead, declare them outside the loop, and simply pass them in. `function myMouseLeave(e) {...}` ...then in the loop... `layoutBox[x].addEventListener("mouseleave", myMouseLeave)`

Comment: Also, while I coped your `.slice()` calls above, it can be more succinctly done as `[].forEach.call(layoutBox, function(el, i) {`. This is a common mistake.

Comment: Overall, this seems like a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for this. Apart from moving the variables (for now), I've implemented your suggestions. It only runs once now, rather than x amount of times, so that's good. But It's erroring at _el.querySelectorAll is not a function_.


I'm not sure I understand what you mean by passing `this` in to the event handlers.

Comment: I mean whenever you call `moveMask`, you need to be sure to pass an element as the first argument. So in the `mousemove` event handler *(I guess that was the only one)*, you'd do `moveMask(this, xPos, yPos);` so that `this` (the element) is passed as the first argument. I had previously told you to use `.call()`, but that's not necessary if you can avoid creating the `coords` array.

Comment: [Here's a rewrite](https://jsfiddle.net/guvmqgmh/) that I did. It assumed that the `coords` and `rect` variables were not needed outside the functions because that's the only place they were used. If they're needed for other code, then you can revert those.

Comment: ...just saw your updated code. The problem is with `moveMask.call(null, coords);`. If you do need the `coords` array, and you don't want to add `this` to it, then you could do `moveMask(this, coords[0], coords[1])`

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you! `coords` and `rect` weren't needed outside the functions, so that rewrite is perfect. And I didn't need to array, so calling the function and passing `this` as the first value was enough.

Comment: As you can probably tell, my JS isn't great... Are there any books you could recommend, to help me improve? Thanks for the link to the code review site, didn't realise that existed until now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118242/discussion-between-luke-and-squint).